# Floating of gallery image

Tags: html, css, gallery

In [this gallery](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/msb/exkl-stuckmarmor.html) the last image should float to the left but it is positioned in the middle. Whats wrong with the code?

[This is the whole code CSS](http://pastebin.com/wV7XNfLQ).

[This is the whole code HTML](http://pastebin.com/HL11LWNZ).

HTML:

`<div class="text-block7" >
<a href="gal/60.png" class="gal2" rel="gal"><img src="gal/thumb/60.png" alt=""></a>
</div>`

CSS:

```
#rightcolumn-12 .text-block7 { width: 239px; height: 190px; display: block; float: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the 7th `div` block add:

```
<div style="clear:left"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

this happens because your 4th image is higher, so the 7th image when is floating to the left is slamming against that element.

to prevent this kind of behaviour just define a css rule that applies a `clear:left` on every `3n + 1` div involved: e.g.

```
div[class^="text-block"]:nth-child(3n + 1) {
   clear: left;
}
```

Note: the `nth-child` pseudoclass unfortunately doesn't work on `IE8`, but if you need to absolutely support that browser you may simply use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top` instead of floating elements

Comment: A CSS fix is probably better than adding extra markup like my solution, depends on what browser support is needed I guess. Thinking about IE8 :P

Comment: that's why I often use `inline-blocks` instead of `float` for this kind of task, @NickR :)